# modifying the contents of the sqlilte database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have the following sqlite3 database:

```
name : sampledb

table  : main



fields :  id, name description and gender
```

sample elements are:

```
"1" "John"  "Fat-Head"  "M"
```

I have around 2000 rows, and want to remove the quotes from each of the field values, so that my db elements look like:

```
1 John Fat-Head M
```

What would be an efficient way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using python for this task (if so, post what you have so far), or do you want to? Is this a database that you generated (incorrectly) with quotes? If so, you may want to modify the generating code so it doesn't insert the quotes in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure the quotes are actually in the database? How are you determining this to be the case?

Comment: i use sqliteman to see the database table, no i have not used python, but an answer in python would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this will be one hundred percent there, or very efficient but try this:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('sampledb')
c = db.cursor()

new_set = []

c.execute('select * from main')

temp_value = []
for row in c:
     for item in row:
          temp_value.append(item[1:-1])
     new_set.append(temp_value)
     temp_value = []

# place it back into the database
```

Hope this is enough of a guideline!